# Netlify Forms - Empty Submission - Vue (Gridsome)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, netlify, gridsome

I hate to do this (share the whole code), but I feel like I have no other choice. I have been banging my head against the wall for the past two days. It is one issue after another. Currently, I am soooo close to getting Forms working.

For some reason an empty field is submitted. I can't find the reason, it is really hard to debug.

```js
<template>
          <form
          name="add-subscriber"
          id="myForm"
          method="post"
          data-netlify="true"
          data-netlify-honeypot="bot-field"
          @submit.prevent="handleFormSubmit">
            <input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="add-subscriber" />
            <input type="email" name="email" v-model="formData.userEmail">
            <button type="submit" name="button">Subscribe</button>
          </form>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            formData: {},
        }
    },

    methods: {
        encode(data) {  
            return Object.keys(data)
                .map(key => `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(data[key])}`)
                .join("&");
            },

        handleFormSubmit(e) {
            const axiosConfig = {
                header: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }
            };

            axios.post(
                location.href, 
                this.encode({
                    'form-name': e.target.getAttribute("name"),
                    ...this.formData,
                }),
                axiosConfig
            )
            .then(data => console.log(data))
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
            .then(document.getElementById("myForm").innerHTML = `<div>Almost there! Check your inbox for a confirmation e-mail.</div>`)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

If there is anything that comes to mind or jumps at you, I would really appreciate your help! Thanks a ton in advance.

P.S. I used the guides from [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2018/09/07/how-to-integrate-netlify-forms-in-a-vue-app/) and [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/using-netlify-forms-and-netlify-functions-to-build-an-email-sign-up-widget/)

---

### Edit

The Params of my POST request seem legit:

```
-----------------------------171747581031589150472368446206
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="form-name"

add-subscriber
-----------------------------171747581031589150472368446206
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userEmail"

me@rasul.com
-----------------------------171747581031589150472368446206--
```

However, the response is a little weird. It is returning the whole page, for some reason:

[image]

Comment: It's been awhile since I've used Vue, but I imagine you need to bind `v-model` to "form.userEmail".

Comment: I see what you mean. I changed the code accordingly, unfortunately, this didn't help, the problem remains.

Comment: Do you need `userEmail` to be in the `formData`? I think the problem is that  `userEmail` is not initialized. Could you try  `userEmail : null` in the data and check the result?

Comment: I've added `userEmail: null`... I think it worked! Thanks

Comment: If you want to submit it as an answer I will gladly Approve!